# How send data from service to thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

In my service-thread:

```
public class Main_Service extends Service implements Runnable {
... }
```

I want to send broadcast data:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
         while (true) {
           try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                if (Draw_picture != null) 
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Picture copy");
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("picture", Draw_picture);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In other a Thread I do the following:

```
public Intent mServiceIntent;
mServiceIntent = new Intent(context, Main_Service.class);
context.startService(mServiceIntent);
```

In the runnable method I put the following code:

```
mpubl_picture = (Bitmap) mServiceIntent.getExtras().get("picture");
 if (mpubl_picture != null)
    {
    Log.i(TAG, "mpubl_picture is not null ");
    }
```

But when I debug, **mpubl_picture** = null, Draw_picture!=null. Whats wrong?

Comment: I think a little more explanation about the error will be helpfull

Comment: Also in Android you should use AsyncTask, it's always a better idea then regular Threads